# EF5 no referential constraint for 1 to 1 or 0..1 to 1 relationships?

Tags: entity-framework

When creating an association, by default the box to create a referential constraint is grayed out for 1:1 and 0..1:1 relationships. Any idea why it's like this?

NVM - it actually throws a lot of errors when creating the referential constraint. What's up with that?

Comment: Only one key - and that's of course the parent table.

Comment: NVM - it actually throws a lot of errors when creating the referential constraint. What's up with that?

Comment: Okay - the PK of the second table does not correspond to the PK of the parent table - but instead another property of the child table corresponds to the PK of the parent table.

Comment: Anybody here? I'd really like an answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a referential constraint with a 1-1 using non-primary-key properties you have to create a one-to-many or zero-or-one-to-many relationship and then define a foreign key. EF doesn't support 1 to 1 or 0..1 to 1 relationships that don't use the primary-key property.